# "open buffer here" in emacs (ido-mode)

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using emacs in ido-mode. When selecting a desired buffer, instead of the buffer showing up in the current window I will be taken to a separate frame and window in which the buffer is already open. Is there a way to modify (turn off) this behavior? It seems like something I expect from (pop-to-buffer) but in ido.el there is no such reference that I can find. I think it's an ido-mode "feature" because it does not happen when I start emacs with the -q option. Thanks much in advance...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ido-default-buffer-method` may be what you are looking for, it has the same possible values as `ido-default-file-method`, and directs you to its help, which is:

```
ido-default-file-method is a variable defined in `ido.el'.
Its value is raise-frame

Documentation:
How to visit a new file when using `ido-find-file'.
Possible values:
`selected-window' Show new file in selected window
`other-window'    Show new file in another window (same frame)
`display'     Display file in another window without selecting to it
`other-frame'     Show new file in another frame
`maybe-frame'     If a file is visible in another frame, prompt to ask if you
                  you want to see the file in the same window of the current
                  frame or in the other frame
`raise-frame'     If a file is visible in another frame, raise that
                  frame; otherwise, visit the file in the same window
```

Comment: In my case ido-default-buffer-method appears to be the variable I need to change but this led me right to it! Thank you ~